# Xml в проектировании GUI

Tags: xml, gui, книги

Здравствуйте, хотелось бы узнать следующее. Я слышал, в опен сорсе часто использую xml в проектировании GUI, и что все это выливается в большое количество положительных моментов, по типу перевода интерфейса на другие языки. Гугл сходу мне ничего приличного не выдал, может кто-то может указать учебник или книгу, где можно было бы почерпнуть знаний, касательно этого вопроса?

Comment: О чём идёт речь? Какой язык? Web/Java/NET/XUL?? Контекст какой?

Comment: Я хотел узнать скорее теоретические основы, то есть каким образом применяется, как используется на практике. Конечной, мой вопрос из разряда "слышал звон", но более конкретно не могу сказать. Что касательно языка применения, то Java, Python, пойму оба варианта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если рассматривать Java, то тут всё зависит от направления. Лично я сталкивался с XML, используемом для разметки UI для Android.

Есть также такая штука как UiBinder в GWT. Там XML также используется для описания и разметки UI.

Есть некая тула, которая генерирует код для Swing'а из XML.. не припомню точно названия, но легко можно найти при желании.

Про Python, к сожалению, ничего не могу сказать, но подозреваю, что нечто подобное должно быть и для питона.

Comment: в Python с UI из xml сталкивался только в PyQt библиотеке, более ярких да и вообще примеров привести не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Если брать .NET, то в WPF используют XAML разметку. XAML - это подмножество XML. Критическое преимущество подобного подхода в разделении внешнего вида приложения и его поведения. Получается возможным разделить дизайн и программирование. Как следствие радикально упрощается тестирование пользовательских интерфейсов. В WPF принято использовать MVVM (есть шаблон для Visual Studio от Microsoft). Для начала можно почитать здесь:

[Приложения WPF с шаблоном проектирования модель-представление-модель представления](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dd419663.aspx).